# Keycloak 18.0.2 Concurrent Login Issue

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I am integrating Keycloak with Sitecore and I want to limit concurrent user login where from the Sitecore side only one user can log in with the same credential. I am using Keycloak 18.0.2 version. Below settings I have done:

[image]

[image]

After this setting when I am loading `http://localhost:8080/` it shows an `Already Login` message.

[image]

My problem is that I want to limit the Sitecore user, not the Keycloak user.